# Create view from 2 tables with one table precedence with other table (mostly both tables are similar except one col)

Tags: sql, oracle, join, view

Create view from 2 tables with one table precedence with other table (mostly both tables are similar except one col).

Need a view from 2 tables.

```
Table1 table contains below columns with values:
ValueOne = C11
ValueTwo= C12
ValueThree= C13

Table2 table contains below columns (extra id column compare to table1).   
Id = 123   
ValueOne = C11  
ValueTwo= V12  
ValueThree= C13
```

Table2 is precedence over Table1. When w query with ID, and if Id is not there it has to pick the values from Table1. If the Id is available then it has to pick the values from Table2.

For this I need a view to combine these 2 tables and when we query from view we need to get proper results.

```
example: 1) Select * from ViewName where ID=123
 then in this case I have to get below values (from table2, as the ID exist in the table2):   
 Id = 123   
ValueOne = C11   
ValueTwo= V12   
ValueThree= C13   

2) Select * from ViewName where ID=01
in this case it has to get the below values (Id and other values from Table1, 
as ID is not there in Table2:   
     Id = 01   
    ValueOne = C11    
    ValueTwo= C12   
    ValueThree= C13
```

Comment: A view which includes two tables presumes some kind of a join. It makes sense if those tables are related, somehow. I don't see any relation between those two tables, so I have no idea how to create a view so that it would return desired data. Besides, where did ID = 01 come from? It doesn't exist in your sample tables.

Comment: @Littlefoot, any other approach is also fine (instead of view is there any way to create it)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use a join. Something like this should work

```
    CREATE VIEW View_1 AS
    select t2.*
    from Table2 t2

    Union ALL

    Select t1.*
    from table1 t1 
    LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID 
    where t2.ID is NULL
```

I did not test but this should give you a good start.

Comment: there is no ID in table1. So on what basis we can join the table (you mentioned there as t1.id=t2.id)?

Comment: That's what you should tell us.

Comment: @Littlefoot, hope I had mentioned in my question (2nd table is similar to first table only one extra column i.e. ID).

Comment: @Gordon Linoff any help on this.

Comment: If you don't know how to join those tables (by the way, didn't you read a comment I posted below the question?), how are we supposed to know that? So - in my opinion - no: what you *mentioned* isn't enough.

Comment: @mallikgm if there is no ID column in Table1, then I do not think you can join the tables. You could try to join on the three columns ( left join Table 1 on T1.Value1 = T2.Value1 AND T1.Value2=T2.Value2 AND T1.Value3=T2.Value3). However, I would not suggest this.

Comment: @mallikgm No problem! If the solution is correct, please be sure to accept it as the answer.